# Reinstall wordpress/mySQL caused database problem

Tags: database

I just reinstalled Wordpress to fix another problem. I followed careful instructions about backing up my database but now I get error 1062 from mySQL when I try to reinstall the database. This is because a duplicate database seems to have been created, stopping me uploading my saved version.

How can I delete/override the duplicate database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First remove the database which created when install WP. Then try to import your original database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new database with another name and import that backup there. Then go to `wp-config.php` file and replace old database name with the new one and the user and pass if you want to create a new user for that specific database. 
I wouldn't recommend you to delete old version until you setup new database successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've restored my backup database using this method but I'm now getting other error messages. The first three are the same as i was getting before I starting trying to fix anything. Any suggestions for these?

Comment: Warning: include(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/hlmparry/public_html/wp-config.php on line 62

Warning: include(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/hlmparry/public_html/wp-config.php on line 62

Warning: include(): Failed opening '1' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/hlmparry/public_html/wp-config.php on line 62

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/hlmparry/public_html/wp-config.php:62) in /home/hlmparry/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1179

Comment: It means you haven't put right information in wp-config.php file.